# How to share my puTTY SSH tunnel with another computer on LAN

Tags: ssh, putty, remote-access, ssh-tunnel

I have SSH running on my home tomato router and connect to it successfully.

I'm at a client and want one of my co-workers to be able to access a resource I have there and I tried having him connect to my machine (we are both hooked into the router at the client) and I made the below modifications noted above to puTTY:

[image: Port Forwarding Settings]

Though when he enters my ip address and port of 8080 into his browser, it doesn't forward
-I don't see anything in the event log for puTTY for his connection attempts
-I've made sure the firewall is turned off on both machines
-I see his machine making connections to mine via TCPView/netstat (and pings are successful) though it's not connecting to puTTY on my machine, it seems to be intercepted on my machine despite seeing puTTY listening on 8080 and his connections to my machine on 8080

if I set a tunnel to forward on my local machine, like this:

[image: Settings]

I see it in the event log but the local routing doesn't work (though that's not too surprising)

the fact that his machine can communicate at all with puTTY is odd though given that when he tries a dynamic port, it seems intercepted by windows...

any ideas guys ? :)

Comment: I indeed want him to use the router as a SOCKS proxy since nothing is accessible at the client site as I don't have a VPN configured. I tried setting his browser to my machine's ip address and port of 8080 for socks, but that's what isn't working. Is there some firewall setting that might be interfering (though I do believe I turned off the firewalls...)

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic port forwarding is meant to be used as a SOCKS proxy. From [the docs](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.63/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-portfwd):

> Alternatively, select ‘Dynamic’ if you want PuTTY to provide a local SOCKS 4/4A/5 proxy on a local port

Its not meant to be accessed directly in your browser.  If you have a single resource you're trying to access, I would just use the Local Port forwarding pointing to the port of the resource.  Otherwise, you should setup the browser's proxy settings to point to the tunnel.